# Delete OUT time value if it less than IN time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table and am getting some timestamp wrong from our system, I want to delete the out time since I have IN/OUT with same time almost different in seconds.

If `OUT` time less than `IN` with different in sounds, need to be deleted.

My Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT ca.Id
        FROM test m
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 Id
                ,TagID
                ,TIMESTAMP
                ,ZoneCoordinateGroupID
            FROM test tmp
            WHERE tmp.TagID = m.TagID
                --AND tmp.Timestamp > m.Timestamp 
                AND DATEDIFF(SS, TMP.TIMESTAMP, m.TIMESTAMP) > 30
                AND tmp.Id > m.Id
            ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
            ) AS ca
        )
```

Data as:

```
ID      TagID           AntennaID   RSSI    Timestamp                   TagData ZoneCoordinateGroupID   ZType DBTimeStamp       BatteryStatus   Longitude   Latitude    Accuracy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
169343  0.432.076.708   6           -97     2016-09-06 02:36:58.817     1004    OUT                     2016-09-06 06:36:59.320 Good            NULL        NULL        NULL
169347  0.432.076.708   7           -95     2016-09-06 02:37:00.440     1006    IN                      2016-09-06 06:37:01.390 Good            NULL        NULL        NULL
169714  0.432.076.708   8           -92     2016-09-06 03:57:31.713     1004    OUT                     2016-09-06 07:57:33.077 Good            NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want to get.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the thing is am not getting any result from the query as I need to delete the first record that showing out time so whenever I have OUT time less than IN time, I want to be deleted since ill have many transactions been generated

Comment: Most probably  `DATEDIFF(SS,TMP.Timestamp,m.Timestamp)` is always negative if `TMP` is supposed to occur after  `m` as `tmp.Id > m.Id` implies . Check it first.